# javascript set left absolute position based on window height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move an absolute position `div` based on `window.innerHeight`. for example, if the `win height` is 700px, the `div` would have style `left:100px`, then if the height is `600px` the style will be `left: 78px`.

please let me know how to calculate it. I am trying using `regression linear` formula, but honestly I am confuse.

PS: I don't want to use `CSS` media query, it really need to be responsive based on window height.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where's your code?

Comment: to be honest, I have no idea using regression linear. so, no code yet has been done :(

Comment: have you tried using 'vh' viewport height instead of 'px'?

Comment: That is basic math? `y = m*x + b` is a [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function_(calculus)). You got two points: `(700 | 100)` and `(600 | 78)` and can therfor solve it.

Comment: yep, basic math. I need to learn more Math. anyway, using `vh` seems solving the problem. @JordiFlores, please make it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @DarielPratama done, just now, I don't know why someone downbotted it. Please, could you mark it as solved? Nice it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `vh` unit instead of pixels, or use the `calc` function.

Loot at this example and how they work:

```css
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

.myHeight {
width: 100px;
height: calc(100% - 20%);
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
background-color:cyan;
color: #000;
}
.myVhHeight {
width: 100px;
height: 40vh;
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
background-color: green;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="myHeight">
this uses 80% of total height with 'calc'
</div>
<div class="myVhHeight">
this uses 40% of view port  height with 'vh'
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know you are asking for a JS solution but ..
Have you tried using responsive / conditional style classes by defining?

```
@media screen( height: 700px ){ /* min-height, max-height, etc */
  div{
    left: 100px;
  }
}
@media screen( height: 600px ){ /* min-height, max-height, etc */
  div{
    left: 78px;
  }
}
```

In JS you can use:

```
var divs = document.querySelector('div');
var left = (window.innerHeight == 700) ? 100 : 78 ;
for(var div in divs){
   div.style.left = left + 'px';
}
```

You can also use maths:

```
var refLeft = 100, refHeight = 700;
var newHeight = window.innerHeight();
var left = newHeight * refLeft / refHeight;
```

And then:

```
var divs = document.querySelector('div');
for(var div in divs){
   div.style.left = left + 'px';
}
```

Comment: thank you, but as I said, i don't want to use CSS media query. and the window.innerHeight not just between 700 and 800.

Comment: nope, I didn't -1 you, why should I? `vh` unit solve my problem, and I don't have problem with you.

Comment: Haha .. excuse me then. Someone else did.